# Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}, -1<x<2$, zero elsewhere, be the p.d.f. of $X$. Find the c.d.f. and the p.d.f. of $Y=X^2$.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm having trouble figuring out the appropriate domains.

The space of $X$ is given by $\mathscr{A} = \{x: -1<x<2\}$ and the p.d.f. of $X$ is given by $$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3},&-1<x<2 &\\ 0,& \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Then the c.d.f. of $X$ will be found by \begin{align} F_{X}(x) &= \int_{-1}^{x}f_{X}(w)\;dw \\ &= \int_{-1}^{x}\frac{1}{3}\;dw \\ &= \frac{1}{3}w|_{w=-1}^{w=x} \\ &= \frac{1}{3}(x+1)\end{align}
for $-1<x<2$.

So overall, $$F_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &x \leq -1 &\\ \frac{1}{3}(x+1), &-1<x<2 &\\ 1, &2 \leq x \end{cases}$$

I'm worried I've gotten $F_{X}(x)$ wrong because if we consider $Y=X^2$, then the space of $Y$ must be $\mathscr{B} = \{y: y=x^2 \text{  for } x \in \mathscr{A}\} = \{y: 0 \leq y<1\} \cup \{y: 1 \leq y <4\}$ and if I try finding $F_{Y}(y)$ based on $F_{X}(x)$, how would I account for the space of $Y$?

---

Continuing after comments:

To find $F_{Y}(y)$, we observe that --> $$F_{Y}(y) = Pr(Y \leq y) = Pr(X^2 \leq y) = Pr(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y})$$

By the properties of the c.d.f., we know $$Pr(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_{X}(\sqrt{y}) - F_{X}(-\sqrt{y}) = \frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{y}+1)-\frac{1}{3}(-\sqrt{y}+1)=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{y}$$

That is, we have --> $$F_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} 0, &y < 0 &\\ \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{y}, &0 \leq y<4 &\\ 1, &4 \leq y \end{cases}$$

And so --> $$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3\sqrt{y}} ,& 0 < y<4 &\\ 0,& \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

However, this p.d.f must be incorrect since $\int_{0}^4 f_{Y}(y) \; dw= \frac{4}{3} > 1$, which is no good. What am I doing wrong?

---

Okay - this is just for my future reference, but thanks for the helpful comments as I can now solve this problem; please see solution below.

We know
\begin{align}
Pr(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq\sqrt{y})
&=F_{X}(\sqrt{y})-F_{X}(-\sqrt{y})\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[0,2]}-\frac{1}{3}(-\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{-\sqrt{y}\in[-1,0]}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[1,2]}+\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[0,1]}-\frac{1}{3}(-\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[0,1]}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{y}+1)\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[1,2]}+\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{y})\chi_{\sqrt{y}\in[0,1]}
\end{align}
Thus
$$
F_{Y}(y)=
\begin{cases}
0,&y<0\\
\frac{2\sqrt{y}}{3},&0\leq y<1\\
\frac{\sqrt{y}+1}{3},&1\leq y<4\\
1,&4\leq y
\end{cases}
$$
And so
$$
f_{Y}(y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3\sqrt{y}},&0<y\leq 1\\
\frac{1}{6\sqrt{y}},&1<y\leq 4\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
The End.

Comment: Your $F_X(x)$ looks good to me.

Comment: You can get the density function for Y by getting the density for |X|.

Comment: @peterwhy Hi Peter. So assuming my $F_{X}(x)$ is correct, I went a bit further into the problem by finding the c.d.f. and p.d.f. of $Y = X^2$, but if you can take another look at my solution (after the horizontal line break), you'll see that I arrive at the wrong results. If you have the time, please take another look as I am stuck on this.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Hi - I'm not sure how finding the density for $|X|$ will help me here?

Comment: The mistake that you are making is in assuming that for _all_ choices of $y\in[0,4]$, $F_X(-\sqrt{y})$ has value $\frac 13(-\sqrt{y}+1)$. The claim that $F_X(-\sqrt{y})$ equals $\frac 13(-\sqrt{y}+1)$  _is_ valid when $y\in[0,1]$, but for $y\in(1,4]$, $-\sqrt{y} < -1$, and so $F_X(-\sqrt{y})$ has value $0$.  In short, your $f_Y(y)$ is given by one expression when $y\in[0,1]$ and a different expression when $y\in(1,4]$.

Comment: @Ash Check your $F_X(-\sqrt y)$ for $1\le y \le 4$.